# Initiate a long-running `LOAD DATA FROM S3` Aurora/MySQL query from AWS lambda?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-aurora

We have a serverless AWS lambda function that initiates a long-running data import query on an `Aurora/MySQL 8` RDS instance using `LOAD DATA FROM S3`.

When I say "long-running" I mean potentially longer than the 15 minute lambda limit. In some cases it may be much longer.

I thought I could initiate this query from a python thread, and then exit, but MySQL will roll back the query when it realizes that the client disconnected.

Is there any way to prevent MySQL from terminating the `LOAD DATA FROM S3` query despite losing connection to the client?

The only thing I can think of is to create a new table called `s3_imports` and set a `TRIGGER` on insert to this table. The `TRIGGER` would then start the `LOAD DATA FROM S3` operation.

Is there a better way? Everything I search regarding this says to use `disown` or `nohup` or `screen` or `tmux` — none of these things apply to my situation.

Comment: Hi @mike-furlender. Sorry this isn't an answer to your question. But would you mind telling me how you got a lambda to submit LOAD DATA FROM S3 sucessfully? What langauage and mysql connector / driver are you using? Everthing I have tried (using mysql prepare, having LOAD DATA FROM S3 in a sproc) fails due to it not being a supported statement. Thanks.

Comment: @ajg I believe "LOAD DATA FROM S3" is only supported on Aurora. I am using python 3.7 and a native C mysql driver, but I don't think that should matter. I can run it interactively through an SQL GUI and it will still work.

Comment: Thanks for the reponse @mike-furlender. I actually finally got it to work a couple of days ago so thought I'd add how in case it helps anyone else. We are using node and the mysql2 package. Was trying the execute() method which fails as underneath it does mysql prepare which rejects the LOAD DATA command. Turns out it works using the mysql2 query() method, as long as you run "SET ROLE AWS_LOAD_S3_ACCESS;" first. think this last part is needed if using the non admin account and varies between mysql versions, so google if stuck here.